# HEROKU deploing executable jar

Tags: java, heroku, executable-jar, heroku-cli

I created a bot for discord. Then i created executable jar file by eclipse (maven project). Then i deploing this file in heroku, using this documentation [enter link description here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-executable-jar-files)
And its worked, but then app crashed by R10 error.

my Procfile  web (Free): java $JAVA_OPTS -jar jarvis.jar  $JAR_OPTS

Logs 
2018-10-07T19:08:05.426794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Webprocess failed to bind to $PORT within 90 seconds of launch
2018-10-07T19:08:05.426794+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2018-10-07T19:08:05.566438+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2018-10-07T19:08:05.579345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

How can i fixed it?

Comment: in documentation i using only Using the Heroku Java CLI plugin

Comment: I'm not sure how Discord bots run. Does yours respond to HTTP requests? Heroku expects your application to do this, just as a regular web application would, and it gives you a port to use for that purpose. Your code isn't listening on the provided port.

Comment: how i can do this?

Comment: Please answer my question first: is your bot supposed to respond to HTTP requests? If it isn't it probably isn't a good fit for Heroku.

Comment: no its connected by discord standalone app

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Does it run, waiting for HTTP requests (e.g. from a web browser, or a webhook, or an API request from Discord, etc.), and respond to them?

Comment: i think it waits for some HTTP request from Discord API as when i write a msg in a chat it sends request to discord servers and then they send request to the bot. Is this the answer for your question?

Comment: Okay, then wherever you set up your HTTP server (you haven't shown that to us), you need to use the port given by the `PORT` environment variable.

Comment: oo its works but only when i entered on app hosts page https://sushi231.herokuapp.com else  app shoutdown                                                            
2018-10-07T22:43:04.462105+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2018-10-07T22:45:03.686010+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-10-07T22:45:03.961234+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143

Answer (score 0):

If the bot doesn't handle HTTP requests, you'll need a `Procfile` with a process type other than `web:`.